# Windows Toggle to Disable/Enable Wired Connection

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to quickly toggle the internet connection on my PC, *including* wired connections? Its a hassle to open Control Panel and disable/enable the ethernet adapter every time I want to go offline. (Note: I am on windows 10)

Comment: You can create a batch file with NETSH WLAN CONNECT and DISCONNECT commands. Disconnecting Wireless will cause Wired to connect. If no Ethernet is plugged in, Wireless disconnect puts you offline. If Metrics are default automatic, this will all occur automatically.  I do this on my own Windows 10 machine.

Comment: oh nice, I'll probably alter it a bit but the command is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @John feel free to post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: I did post an answer for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file with `NETSH WLAN CONNECT` and `DISCONNECT` commands.

```
NETSH WLAN DISCONNECT Interface= ...

NETS WLAN CONNECT  Interface= ...
```

Disconnecting Wireless will cause Wired to connect.

If no Ethernet is plugged in, Wireless disconnect puts you offline.

If Metrics are default automatic, this will all occur automatically. I do this on my own Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution without the need to specify the titles of interfaces, e.g. for it to work in different localizations. With [CNic](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/TechniquesForSimp2006_05.exe) (36KB) I use `CNic n:0 -c&pause&CNic n:0 -d` to switch the wired connection. `CNic -l` will list your interfaces. Or [devcon](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe) (76KB).